# Internet Explorer Automation: textbox with dropdown when typing

Tags: javascript, vb.net, vba, internet-explorer, ie-automation

I am automating a page with multiple textboxes that require the text to be manually typed, [textbox image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIN80.png)

while typing, a dropdown with the possible matches will appear and I need to select the value to proceed. 
[textbox image with dropdown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e56Gc.png)

If I automatically set the correct text for the textbox ex. getelementbyid().innertext or .text then I will encounter an error when I submit the form but when it is manually typed and selected it will proceed without error. How can I automate this? Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: What is the error message you get?